# How to find the DB host within the ec2/docker?

Tags: docker, amazon-ec2

I launched an EC2 instance and installed docker. Then, I pulled a postgres DB image and ran the database. docker ps command shows the container id and the port 5432.
I tried to run my application image with db endpoint and it fails as it wasn't able to connect to the db.
It worked in my local machine if I use host as kubernetes.docker.internal in the db endpoint. How to find out the host for the db which is running in the docker container? Thank you.

Comment: The [sample applications](https://docs.docker.com/samples/) in the Docker documentation have a couple of multi-container setups including a local database in a container.  I'd suggest working through one of these examples locally.  If you have a working setup with perhaps a `docker-compose.yml` file to launch it, you should be able to migrate it to the EC2 instance.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, ifconfig command helped me to resolve the issue. I took the ip listed under "docker0" and used in the db endpoint. Make sure the database is started and it's listening to port 5432 (netstat -na | grep "5432").